# protobuf-net cannot deserialize from google protobuf if there is an abstract class

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have *.Net Client* and *.Net Server* and they are using *protobuf-net* for communication. Now I have to create a *Java Client* to communicate with *.Net Server* and to do that I have to use *google protobuf* but I have an issue:

*protobuf-net* are failing during deserialization of an object which is sent from *Java Client* via *google protobuf*, *protobuf-net* shows the next error: 'No parameterless constructor found for ProtobufClasses.BasePage' but if I send the same object from *.Net Client* via *protobuf-net* then everything works. The reason of failure: it's happening because of *abstract* type.

**Please note: I cannot touch server's code at all**

---

Here is a small example of whole structure:

**Server classes:**

```
[ProtoContract]
public class LoginPage : BasePage 
{
[ProtoMember(2)]
public sting Name { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(100, typeof(LoginPage))]
public abstract class BasePage
{
[ProtoMember(1)]
public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

**Example of *.proto* file:**

```
message LoginPage
{
 string Name = 2;
}

message BasePage
{
 oneof subtype
 {
  LoginPage LoginPage = 100;  
 }
 int32 Id = 1;
}
```

---

**Scenario N1** (*protobuf-net* -> *protobuf-net*)

```
            var obj = new LoginPage();

            byte[] array = null;

            //Serializing to array
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, obj);

                array = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }

            LoginPage obj2;

            //Deserializing from array
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(array))
            {
                obj2 = Serializer.Deserialize<LoginPage>(stream);
            }
```

**Everhithing is working**

---

**Scenario N2** (*protobuf-net* -> *google protobuf* -> *protobuf-net*)

```
            //xxxNN - means [protobuf-net] object
            //xxxGG - means [google protobuf] object 

            var objNN = new LoginPage();

            byte[] arrayNN = null;

            //Serializing via [protobuf-net] to array
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, objNN);

                arrayNN = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }

            Protobuf.BasePage objGG = null;

            //Deserializing to [google protobuf] from [protobuf-net] array
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(arrayNN))
            {
                objGG = Protobuf.BasePage.Parser.ParseFrom(stream);
            }

            byte[] arrayGG = null;

            //Serializing via [google protobuf] to array
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                objGG.WriteTo(stream);

                arrayGG = stream.ToArray();
            }

            LoginPage objN;

            //Deserializing to [protobuf-net] from [google protobuf] array
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(arrayGG))
            {
                objN = Serializer.Deserialize<LoginPage>(stream); // Exception will be shown
            }
```

**Exception is present:** *'No parameterless constructor found for Protobuf.BasePage'*

---

How it possible that it works with *protobuf-net* but doesn't work with *google protobuf*? And how to avoid it? Please note that I cannot change server's code.

Comment: Protocol buffers has no concept of inheritance; protobuf-net *fakes it*, but you need to *opt in* for that (`[ProtoInclude(...)]`), and it maps to very specific concepts in terms of the overall protobuf ecology; it is very hard to comment on what *should* happen in this case without seeing **what you're sending from the Java side**

Comment: it is *possible* that protobuf-net here is angry about the *order*, i.e. it isn't very happy if Java is sending the `Id` before the sub-type; as an experiment, you could try inverting that so that the *low* field numbers are the sub-type; that's something that protobuf-net could improve, and it may tie fairly neatly into some work that is going on currently